# SAP and .NET through SOAP

Tags: c#, .net, soap, sap-basis

In the near future I have to develop an interface for integration between SAP and one other program. It seems that we will do that by the use SAP Business Connector (SBC) by the use of SOAP protocol. But until now I didn't work with SOAP. I tried to search through Google but didn't find something intelligible. and now I am in prostration :-)

Can anyone give me any idea how to develop the SOAP client on .Net? And tutorials, articles or something like this?

I will be thanks in additionally if somebody give me such links with code examples with SOAP clients for SAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone give me any idea how to develop the SOAP client on .Net?

Use a WCF Client: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx

The idea is to generate a strongly typed proxy classes using the `svcutil.exe` command or the Add Service Reference dialog in Visual Studio and point to the WSDL endpoint of the SOAP web service exposed:

```
svcutil http://foo.com/MyService/SomeService?wsdl
```

This will generate a strongly typed class that you could integrate into your project and directly invoke the SOAP methods on it.